# What is Shakespeare in the documentation of Fragments?

Tags: android, android-listview, static

In the documentation of Fragments (http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) at the bottom of the page, we click on an item to show some informations, and we use this :  `Shakespeare.DIALOGUE[getShownIndex()]`

Is `Shakespeare` a static class in the application?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The complete source, including the Shakespeare class, is available in

`SDK_HOME\samples\PLATFORM\legacy\ApiDemos\src\com\example\android\apis\Shakespeare.java`

Basically it just holds strings for the purposes of demo.

Looking at it:

```
public static final String[] DIALOGUE = 
{
        "So shaken as we are, so wan with care," +
        "Find we a time for frighted peace to pant," +
        ... 
};
```

Comment: Nice, so using this was for this example for the sake of clarity, and in the Notepad we use URIs each time we click on a item, are URIs the common way to call some data after we click on a list view?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. In the example the Shakespeare class is just a handy way to store and retrieve text to display. You can do whatever you want when you click on a listview item, you don't need to use URIs.

Comment: Looking at the demo, they are using URIs because they are using ContentProviders, it's just a way to access/look up data and not really a core part of that demo, (and not a core part of how fragments work) I would say.

Comment: Edit: well is it ok, I think I got it. Thanks a lot for your answer

Comment: I don't really use content providers much since most of my data stays internal to my apps - maybe someone else can comment. Does all your data need to be accessed by another app? I tend to store everything in my own sqlite db and just pass ids around, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Yes Shakespeare is a static class in the application. in this class title and summary of Shakespeare's plays are declared so data from this class will be used in the application

Two arrays with title and dialogue are declared in the class. You can check the class on you system's drive where you have installed android setup using following path Android\android-sdk\samples\android-19\legacy\ApiDemos\src\com\example\android\apis

Answer (score 1):

It refers to the `Shakespeare.java` in your SDK's example projects. For example in SDK 19 it is found in `samples/android-19/legacy/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis`.